# MySQL replacement of values in the query result

Tags: mysql

I transpose table rows to columns by the SELECT statement:

```
`SELECT cdcb_info.CISLO AS "cislo", 
max(case when info = 'HBR' then value end) as "HBR", 
max(case when info = 'HCD' then value end) as "HCD" 
FROM cdcb_info group by cdcb_info.CISLO`
```

Result looks like this:

| cislo | HBR | HCD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111222 | 0 | 5 |
| 333444 | 1 | 3 |

how should I modify the query to change the values 0 and 1 to "zero" and "one" for the column HBR and
5, 3 to "five" and "three" for column HCD? Thanks for any help. David

Data example:

```
id  CISLO  info  value
27  111222  HBR 0
28  111222  HCD 5
29  333444  HBR 1
30  333444  HCD 3
```

Comment: Can you add the example table data that query uses to generate that output?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise adding another table, where in one column there are numbers (primary index), in the other the designations of these numbers. Connect this table and output string values from this new table instead of max(case when info = 'HBR' then value end) and max(case when info = 'HCD' then value end).